# android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISCONNECTED (2): cancelRequest:473: Camera device no longer alive

Tags: android, webrtc, android-camera, android-camera2

Running my app, I can see the ***perfect Camera View***, now I open the ***inbuilt Camera app*** and again switch to my own app (here, I am ***getting only black screen***)

Log

```
2020-12-26 16:57:45.696 16445-16768/app.video I/CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state now CAMERA_STATE_IDLE for client app.video API Level 2
2020-12-26 16:57:45.883 16445-16768/app.video I/CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state now CAMERA_STATE_CLOSED for client app.video API Level 2
2020-12-26 16:57:45.886 16445-16596/app.video E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating: 
    android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISCONNECTED (2): cancelRequest:473: Camera device no longer alive
        at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:1127)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:97)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1151)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:526)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$2.onDisconnected(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:737)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$7.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:244)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
     Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: cancelRequest:473: Camera device no longer alive (code 4)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2102)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2056)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
        at android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceUser$Stub$Proxy.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUser.java:676)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:95)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1151) 
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:526) 
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$2.onDisconnected(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:737) 
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$7.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:244) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 
2020-12-26 16:57:45.886 16445-16596/app.video I/org.webrtc.Logging: Camera2Session: Stop internal
2020-12-26 16:57:45.887 16445-16596/app.video I/org.webrtc.Logging: SurfaceTextureHelper: stopListening()
2020-12-26 16:57:45.887 16445-16468/app.video W/app.video: Long monitor contention with owner CaptureThread (16596) at boolean android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int)(BinderProxy.java:-2) waiters=0 in void android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$CameraDeviceCallbacks.onCaptureStarted(android.hardware.camera2.impl.CaptureResultExtras, long) for 381ms
2020-12-26 16:57:45.890 16445-16596/app.video I/org.webrtc.Logging: Camera2Session: Stop done
2020-12-26 16:57:45.890 16445-16596/app.video I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraCapturer: Stop capture
2020-12-26 16:57:45.890 16445-16596/app.video I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraCapturer: Stop capture: Nulling session
2020-12-26 16:57:45.891 16445-16596/app.video I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraCapturer: Stop capture done
2020-12-26 16:57:45.891 16445-16596/app.video I/org.webrtc.Logging: Camera2Session: Camera device closed.
2020-12-26 16:57:45.892 16445-16596/app.video I/org.webrtc.Logging: Camera2Session: Stop camera2 session on camera 0
2020-12-26 16:57:45.892 16445-16768/app.video I/CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_OPEN for client com.sec.android.app.camera API Level 1
2020-12-26 16:57:46.274 16445-16839/app.video I/CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client com.sec.android.app.camera API Level 1
```

XML

```
<com.src.webrtc.android.VideoView
     android:id="@+id/main_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

CODE

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
        this,
        ViewModelFactory.getInstance(application)
    ).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    binding.viewModel = this.viewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this

    binding.apply {
        peerViews.add(mainView)
        peerViews.add(subView1)
        for (i in viewRenderers.indices) {
            viewRenderers[i].setTarget(peerViews[i])
        }
    }

    viewModel.room.observe(this, Observer {
        Log.d(TAG, "observe room $it")
        if (it != null) {
            binding.mainView.apply {
                init(null)
                setScalingType(RendererCommon.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FIT)
                setEnableHardwareScaler(false)
            }
            initSubView(it, binding.subView1)
        } else {
            binding.mainView.clearImage()
            binding.subView1.clearImage()
            Handler().postDelayed({
                binding.mainView.release()
                binding.subView1.release()
            }, 100)
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: You have to re-initialize your camera when resuming your application, in `onResume()`

Comment: @HB. here is the code, I am using in onCreate()  now let me know what I have to use in onResume()

Answer (score 1):

When you are putting your app in the background then detach the camera from this app, you can do this in `onPause()` method and reattach that in `onResume()` method while opening the app again.

Answer (score 0):

do this in your camera `activity`

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        if (AppConstants.isActivityPaused) {//isActivityPaused is boolean var in AppConstant class
            startCamera();
            mBinding.frmCameraPreview.startPreview();
            AppConstants.isActivityPaused = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    AppConstants.isActivityPaused = true;
    try {
        if (mCamera != null) {//mCamera is Camera object
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.lock();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

private void startCamera() {
    mBinding.frmCameraPreview.requestLayout();
    try {
        if (mCamera == null)
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        if (mCamera != null) {
            //setup camera
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Helper method to access the camera returns null if it cannot get the
 * camera or does not exist
 *
 * @return camera
 */
private Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera camera = null;
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
        if (camera == null) {
            camera = getFrontFacingCamera();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return camera;
}


/**
 * if there is no back camera we will get front camera instance
 *
 * @return front camera
 */
private Camera getFrontFacingCamera() {
    int cameraCount;
    Camera cam = null;
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
        }
    }
    if (cam == null)
        cam = Camera.open();
    return cam;
}
```